# Сократить код/убрать копипаст

Tags: java

Я получаю массив `ar` длина которого может быть от 0 до 5 и задача состоит в том чтобы значения из этого массива установить в переменные, а если этих значений нет, установить `99`Так вот я написал код

```
   switch(ar.length){
            case 1:
             this.num1 = ar[0];
             this.num2 = 99;
             this.num3 = 99;
             this.num4 = 99;
             this.num5 = 99;
             break;
         case 2:
             this.num1 = ar[0];
             this.num2 = ar[1];
             this.num3 = 99;
             this.num4 = 99;
             this.num5 = 99;
             break;
         case 3:
             this.num1 = ar[0];
             this.num2 = ar[1];
             this.num3 = ar[2];
             this.num4 = 99;
             this.num5 = 99;
             break;
         case 4:
             this.num1 = ar[0];
             this.num2 = ar[1];
             this.num3 = ar[2];
             this.num4 = ar[3];
             this.num5 = 99;
             break;

         case 5:
             this.num1 = ar[0];
             this.num2 = ar[1];
             this.num3 = ar[2];
             this.num4 = ar[3];
             this.num5 = ar[3];
             break;
         default:
             this.num1 = 99;
             this.num2 = 99;
             this.num3 = 99;
             this.num4 = 99;
             this.num5 = 99;
     }
```

Хотелось бы узнать можно ли сократить ЭТО

Comment: Зачем? Почему не оперировать массивом и данными в нём?

Comment: Не не не, это не аргумент..... в другой функции так же можно оперировать массивом.... а вот это костыляние не ясно опять же накой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, конечно, например так:

```
num1 = arr.length > 0 ? arr[0] : 99;
num2 = arr.length > 1 ? arr[1] : 99;
num3 = arr.length > 2 ? arr[2] : 99;
num4 = arr.length > 3 ? arr[3] : 99;
num5 = arr.length > 4 ? arr[4] : 99;
```

(если не понимаете что это, то почитайте про тернарные операторы, например [тут](https://ru.code-basics.com/languages/java/lessons/ternary-operator))
Вот только зачем? Куда лучше просто брать значения из массива далее в программе, чем переписывать в переменные. Массивы для того и нужны чтобы избегать переменных num{0..n}.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , знаю что, просто в голову не пришло. А num это я для примера написал

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так: arr это ваш масив.

```
arr=['апельсин', 'мандарин'];
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    if(i<arr.length){
        window['num'+(i+1)]=arr[i];
    }else{
        window['num'+(i+1)]=99;
    }
}
```

Comment: А что такое 'window'?

Comment: @DronDron это джедай такой был)

Comment: Ето так мы создаем переменную из строки